# What does this "Challenger" icon mean?

Tags: overwatch

I saw this icon on my Career Profile page and can't figure out what it means.

[image]

Unlike other stats on that page like level and time played, this thing never seems to change.

I don't think I've seen an in-game acknowledgement of it either. So, what does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an unused indicator of your MMR rank for [an upcoming patch that will add a Competitive mode.](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20090466/)

In Closed Beta, there was competitive matchmaking and as such that image you posted is the default image displayed on the Competitive Play screen.

[image: screenshot from Closed Beta]

Note that currently Overwatch does not have a competitive matchmaking system; this answer will be updated appropriately when it is added.

You can see the same format [in this gif Blizzard provided showcasing what competitive ranking will look like.](https://giphy.com/gifs/l4hLP4udsfDAZUwUw)

Comment: Just a friendly reminder you might want to update your answer as you mentioned :)